# How to set border-left for nav menu in css?

Tags: html, css

Here is my worked jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nalinc/rym2zku1/9/

```css
nav ul,
nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav-item ul {
  padding: inherit;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-item ul li:hover {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
.nav-bar {
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .nav-bar--left {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .nav-bar--left .grid-item {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
#nav {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-family: "Raleway", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav-bar--left #nav {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  text-align: right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #nav,
  .nav-bar--left #nav {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
    text-align: inherit;
  }
}
.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 30px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-item {
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
}
#nav>.nav-item {
  border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
#nav>.nav-item.first {
  border-left: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #nav>.nav-item {
    border: 0 none;
  }
}
.nav-item-link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #211f1f;
  font-size: 14px;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.nav-item-link:hover {
  color: #333;
}
.nav-item-link .nav-item.active .nav-item-link {
  color: #333333;
}
.sub-nav .sub-nav {
  display: none !important;
}
.supports-no-csstransforms .sub-nav {
  white-space: normal;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.sub-nav:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 47%;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #211f1f;
  z-index: 40;
}
.sub-nav-item,
#moreMenu--list .nav-item {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #211f1f;
}
.sub-nav-item.first,
#moreMenu--list .nav-item:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.sub-nav-item.last,
#moreMenu--list .nav-item:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.sub-nav-item-link,
#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #0b0a0a;
}
.sub-nav-item-link.first,
.sub-nav-item-link:first-child,
#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link.first,
#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
.sub-nav-item-link:hover,
.sub-nav-item-link:focus,
#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:hover,
#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #0b0a0a;
  background-color: #0b0a0a;
}
.sub-nav-item-link:hover.first,
.sub-nav-item-link:hover:first-child,
.sub-nav-item-link:focus.first,
.sub-nav-item-link:focus:first-child,
#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:hover.first,
#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:hover:first-child,
#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:focus.first,
#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:focus:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
#nav {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center
}
#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 170px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navWrap" role="navigation">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li class="nav-item first active">
      <a class="nav-item-link" href="/">Home</a>                
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-item-link" href="catalog.html">Catalog</a>  
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Data Listing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Web Scheduling</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Google Maps Application</a></li>
      </ul>         
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-item-link" href="/blogs/news">Blog</a>                
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-item-link" href="/pages/about-us">About Us</a>                
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Now I need to `border-left` for each list.

I need like this image:

[image]

When I add `border-left`, it will be touched in the `border-bottom`.

```css
#nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: none;
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the screen shot come from? Look at that website and check how it is styled. Anyway, the answer is to give the border to the `<a>` elements .

Comment: Add the border to the smaller `a` elements, instead of the list items …?

Comment: if i add <a>.. it will be affected other part <a> tag right?

Comment: Yuo can also use the :before element, applied to each first level menu entry, so that it is easy to style it as plain text using font properties

Comment: @rani can you be more specific on what exactly you want to achieve ? I don't understand the `When I add border-left, it will be touched in the border-bottom.` sentence at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## box-shadow hack!

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rym2zku1/29/**

**Additional CSS**

```
.nav-item:not(:last-child) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0px 0px -9px red;
       -moz-box-shadow: 10px 0px 0px -9px red;
            box-shadow: 10px 0px 0px -9px red;
}
```

*Vertical bars coloured red to better highlight the solution*

**Result**

[image]

**Explanation**

We're [ab]using the CSS `box-shadow` property to draw a *partial* border around the `.nav-item` elements.

The "pieces" of the CSS can be described as follows:

1. **Horizontal offset** how far to the right do we want the shadow to sit?
2. **Vertical offset** how far to the bottom do we want the shadow to sit?
3. **Blur radius** how sharp does the shadow want to be?
4. **Spread radius** how far does the shadow spread from its edge?
5. **Colour**

The hack here is that the shadow is nudged 10px to the right but the spread (-9px) works against this to effectively "pull it back" in again. This reduction in spread occurs in all dimensions, so we get a 9px "pull back" from the full-height of the element too.

Answer (score 3):

change  `#nav a` to

```
#nav a {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #666;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go just made the changes that are necessary

```
li {
         border-left:1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rym2zku1/17/

Comment: i need some changes with my existing jsfiddle.. . thanks

Comment: You can try using these selectors in your code and check it out

Comment: if i use for li .. it will be affected another part li in my page right?

Comment: No  cause u can give each ul a id or a class and then specify #id or .class li increase the specificity

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/rym2zku1/21/) should work.

Your CSS (updated):

```
nav ul,nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
  .nav-item  ul{
      padding:inherit;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align:left;
      border-radius:4px;
    }
  .nav-item  ul li:hover{
      background-color:#d1d1d1;
    }
.nav-bar {
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .nav-bar--left {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .nav-bar--left .grid-item {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
#nav {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-family: "Raleway","HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-bar--left #nav {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #nav,.nav-bar--left #nav {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
    text-align: inherit;
  }
}

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-item {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
}

#nav>.nav-item {
  border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

#nav>.nav-item.first {
  border-left: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #nav>.nav-item {
    border: 0 none;
  }
}

.nav-item-link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #211f1f;
  font-size: 14px;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}

.nav-item-link:hover {
  color: #333;
}

.nav-item-link .nav-item.active .nav-item-link {
  color: #333333;
}

.sub-nav .sub-nav {
  display: none !important;
}
.supports-no-csstransforms .sub-nav {
  white-space: normal;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.sub-nav:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 47%;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #211f1f;
  z-index: 40;
}


.sub-nav-item,#moreMenu--list .nav-item {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #211f1f;
}

.sub-nav-item.first,#moreMenu--list .nav-item:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.sub-nav-item.last,#moreMenu--list .nav-item:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.sub-nav-item-link,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #0b0a0a;
}

.sub-nav-item-link.first,.sub-nav-item-link:first-child,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link.first,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

.sub-nav-item-link:hover,.sub-nav-item-link:focus,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:hover,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #0b0a0a;
  background-color: #0b0a0a;
}

.sub-nav-item-link:hover.first,.sub-nav-item-link:hover:first-child,.sub-nav-item-link:focus.first,.sub-nav-item-link:focus:first-child,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:hover.first,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:hover:first-child,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:focus.first,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:focus:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
#nav {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center
}
#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-left : 1px solid #ccc
}
#nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: none;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul li a {
    border-left: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: Correct. I have updated my response with the updated fiddle link. Have added some css at the bottom: 

`#nav ul li a {
    border-left: 0 none;
}`

Comment: I just confused... still i didn't get @ArinCool

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pseudo element for this. A simple solution would be to use the `:before` pseudo element in conjunction to the `first-child` selector. This would allow you to 'add content before, apart from the first child li'

```css
ul{
list-style:none;
  background:lightgray;
  padding:5px;
  border-bottom:1px solid gray;
}
ul li{
display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  transition:all 0.4s;
}

ul li:before{
  content:"|";
  position:absolute;
  left:-10%;
  top:0;
  }

ul li:first-child:before{
  content:"";
  }

ul li:hover{
  background:darkgray;
  color:white;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

---

## Alternative

---

Instead of using an actual `|`, you might want to use a pseudo in a different way:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
ul li:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background: gray;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10%;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
ul li:first-child:before {
  display: none;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: darkgray;
  color: white;
}
ul li:hover:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The border you want is inside the padding (`padding: 2px 30px;`) you add by yourself, as follows:
this avoid to achieve it.

```
.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 30px;
}
```

That can be reached if you give the border inside the `#nav li`.
Here's the fix I try (add this following code in your CSS):

```
#nav li.nav-item{
    border-left:3px solid #000;
}
```

See my **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rym2zku1/32/)**;

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some margin in order to separate it from the container's top/bottom borders:

```
#nav>.nav-item {
   margin:20px 0;
}
```

Comment: OP is talking about the container's top/bottom borders. Check the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the left border to the immediate children (`a`) of `.nav-item`. Then remove the border for the `a` inside the first `.nav-item`. You'll have to mess with the padding and text alignment of the `li` and `a` elements to get the spacing and height of the left borders to look right.

```
.nav-item:first-child > a {
    border: 0;
}
.nav-item > a {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: it shows like this http://s21.postimg.org/97hlg1ycn/Untitled_4.png ... but it is something different from my posted image.. i need that border-left size to small and i need some distance between border-bottom and border-left,,, thanks

Comment: @rani - add padding to the `li` and `text-align: center` to the `a`. Change the padding on the `a` to determine how big the lines should be.

Comment: did you check your mail? I seen your website.. its awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

I’d do something likes thi and then change the `min-width` in the media query to what fits you best on your site.

```css
nav ul,nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
  .nav-item  ul{
      padding:inherit;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align:left;
      border-radius:4px;
    }
  .nav-item  ul li:hover{
      background-color:#d1d1d1;
    }
.nav-bar {
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .nav-bar--left {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .nav-bar--left .grid-item {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
#nav {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-family: "Raleway","HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-bar--left #nav {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #nav,.nav-bar--left #nav {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
    text-align: inherit;
  }
}

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-item {
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
}

#nav>.nav-item.first {
  border-left: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #nav>.nav-item {
    border: 0 none;
  }
}

.nav-item-link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #211f1f;
  font-size: 14px;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}

.nav-item-link:hover {
  color: #333;
}

.nav-item-link .nav-item.active .nav-item-link {
  color: #333333;
}

.sub-nav .sub-nav {
  display: none !important;
}
.supports-no-csstransforms .sub-nav {
  white-space: normal;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.sub-nav:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 47%;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #211f1f;
  z-index: 40;
}


.sub-nav-item,#moreMenu--list .nav-item {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #211f1f;
}

.sub-nav-item.first,#moreMenu--list .nav-item:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.sub-nav-item.last,#moreMenu--list .nav-item:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.sub-nav-item-link,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #0b0a0a;
}

.sub-nav-item-link.first,.sub-nav-item-link:first-child,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link.first,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

.sub-nav-item-link:hover,.sub-nav-item-link:focus,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:hover,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #0b0a0a;
  background-color: #0b0a0a;
}

.sub-nav-item-link:hover.first,.sub-nav-item-link:hover:first-child,.sub-nav-item-link:focus.first,.sub-nav-item-link:focus:first-child,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:hover.first,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:hover:first-child,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:focus.first,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:focus:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
#nav {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center
}
#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: none;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}






/**
 * NEW CODE HERE
**/

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #nav > li {
    position: relative;
  }
  #nav > li:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    width: 1px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: block;
  }

  #nav .first:before {
    content: normal;
  }
}
```

```html
 <nav id="navWrap" role="navigation">
   <ul id="nav">
     <li class="nav-item first active">
       <a class="nav-item-link" href="/">Home</a>                
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-item-link" href="catalog.html">Catalog</a>  
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Data Listing</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Web Scheduling</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Google Maps Application</a></li>
       </ul>         
     </li>

     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-item-link" href="/blogs/news">Blog</a>                
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-item-link" href="/pages/about-us">About Us</a>                
     </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
```

It should work and it should come out exactly as you requested in the image.

Hope you are using a good IDE to write your html and css. I use Microsoft visual studio or sublime text. they easily help you when you cant remember most HTML or CSS tags.

Answer (score 1):

```css
 #nav {
     display:inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
 }

#nav li {
    display:inline-block;

    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    border-left : 1px solid #ccc;
    list-style:none;
}

#nav .first {
    border:none;
}

.nav-item ul { display:none;}
```

```html
 <nav id="navWrap" role="navigation">
                  <ul id="nav">
                     <li class="nav-item first active">
                        <a class="nav-item-link" href="/">Home</a>                
                     </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-item-link" href="catalog.html">Catalog</a>  
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Data Listing</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Web Scheduling</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Google Maps Application</a></li>
    </ul>         
     </li>

                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-item-link" href="/blogs/news">Blog</a>                
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-item-link" href="/pages/about-us">About Us</a>                
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </nav>
```

Do like this

Answer (score 1):

I have updated code have some change in css and it is working as per your requirements

```css
nav#navWrap {

margin: 0 auto;
}
  nav ul,nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
  .nav-item  ul{
      padding:5px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align:left;
      border-radius:4px;
    }
  .nav-item  ul li:hover{
      background-color:#d1d1d1;
    }
.nav-bar {
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .nav-bar--left {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .nav-bar--left .grid-item {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
#nav {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin:10px 20px 0;
  font-family: "Raleway","HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-bar--left #nav {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #nav,.nav-bar--left #nav {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
    text-align: inherit;
  }
}

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px 20px 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-item {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}

#nav>.nav-item>a {
  border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
#nav .nav-item:last-child a{
 border-right: none;
}

#nav>.nav-item.first {
  border-left: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #nav>.nav-item {
    border: 0 none;
  }
}

.nav-item-link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #211f1f;
  font-size: 14px;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}

.nav-item-link:hover {
  color: #333;
}

.nav-item-link .nav-item.active .nav-item-link {
  color: #333333;
}

.sub-nav .sub-nav {
  display: none !important;
}
.supports-no-csstransforms .sub-nav {
  white-space: normal;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.sub-nav:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 47%;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #211f1f;
  z-index: 40;
}


.sub-nav-item,#moreMenu--list .nav-item {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #211f1f;
}

.sub-nav-item.first,#moreMenu--list .nav-item:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.sub-nav-item.last,#moreMenu--list .nav-item:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.sub-nav-item-link,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #0b0a0a;
}

.sub-nav-item-link.first,.sub-nav-item-link:first-child,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link.first,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

.sub-nav-item-link:hover,.sub-nav-item-link:focus,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:hover,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #0b0a0a;
  background-color: #0b0a0a;
}

.sub-nav-item-link:hover.first,.sub-nav-item-link:hover:first-child,.sub-nav-item-link:focus.first,.sub-nav-item-link:focus:first-child,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:hover.first,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:hover:first-child,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:focus.first,#moreMenu--list .nav-item .nav-item-link:focus:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
#nav {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    text-align: center
}
#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 25px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: none;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navWrap" role="navigation">
   <ul id="nav">
    <li class="nav-item first active">
     <a class="nav-item-link" href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-item-link" href="catalog.html">Catalog</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Data Listing</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Web Scheduling</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Google Maps Application</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-item-link" href="/blogs/news">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-item-link" href="/pages/about-us">About Us</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
#nav > li {position: relative}
#nav > li:before {width: 1px; height: 25px; position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 0px; background: #ccc; content: ""}
#nav > li.first:before {display: none}
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rym2zku1/31/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
#nav>.nav-item {
border: 0 none;
}
```

and for **.nav-item** change

```
padding: 0 20px;
margin: 15px auto;
```

Comment: then you didn't say about border-left?

Answer (score 0):

To add border to left use this method

```
li {
     border-left:1px solid gray;
}
```

the above code creates you 1px solid gray color to left of menu

you can even more stylish by adding different color to each `li` by child element

like this

```
li:nth-child(n)
{
         border-left:1px solid gray;
}
```

**n** represent number of li

Check this example using of child element

```css
 #nav {
     display:inline-block;
 }

#nav li {
    display:inline-block;

    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    border-left : 1px solid #ccc;
    list-style:none;
}

#nav li:nth-child(1) {
    border-left: 4px solid green}
#nav li:nth-child(2) {
    border-left: 4px solid darkgoldenrod}
#nav li:nth-child(3) {
    border-left: 4px solid dodgerblue}
#nav li:nth-child(4) {
    border-left: 4px solid firebrick}
.nav-item ul { display:none;}
```

```html
 <nav id="navWrap" role="navigation">
                  <ul id="nav">
                     <li class="nav-item first active">
                        <a class="nav-item-link" href="/">Home</a>                
                     </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-item-link" href="catalog.html">Catalog</a>  
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Data Listing</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Web Scheduling</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Google Maps Application</a></li>
    </ul>         
     </li>

                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-item-link" href="/blogs/news">Blog</a>                
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-item-link" href="/pages/about-us">About Us</a>                
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my trick for this kind of border-left. Go to your jsfiddle and remove line#68, 69, 70 in CSS and paste my code in that place. I hope you are looking for something like that.

```
#nav>.nav-item {
    position: relative;
}

#nav>.nav-item:last-child:after {
    content: none;
}
#nav>.nav-item:after {
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 3px;
    height: 80%;
    width: 1px;
    background: #a8a8a8;
}
```

And don't forget to paste the code below in which viewport you don't want that border.

```
#nav>.nav-item {
   content: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
#nav > li{
 padding:10px 0;
}

#nav > li > a{ 
    padding:5px 20px; /* optional your choice here */
     border-left:1px solid #ccc;   
}
#nav > li:first-child > a{
     border-left:0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what is causing the left border to not appear

```
#nav>.nav-item.first {
border-left: none;
padding-left: 0;
}
```

Removing the border-left and padding left did show the left border for Home